# Могу ли я вместо очередной проверки версии использовать шаблон try-catch?

Tags: java, android

Могу ли я вместо очередной проверки версии

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

использовать шаблон try-catch?

Или почему так делать не стоит?

Comment: [ask] - **Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

код это конечно не сломает, но есть, Петька, нюанс...

1. код будет непонятен. почему тут `try-catch`? с чем это связано? через `if-else` все будет абсолютно понятно, читаемо и логично.
2. `try-catch` - дорогая операция. ее необходимо применять в крайних случаях, когда нет возможности сделать проверку `if-else`.
   например, любимый всеми `NullPointerException` фиксится именно через проверку на `null` через `if-else`, а не через `try-catch`.
3. Кроме того

   `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`
   может применяться для написания кода под различные версии.